# Create one or multiple observables of a subject in a service?

Tags: angular, service, rxjs, observable, behaviorsubject

According to the sources/sites consulted, we can see two approaches of creating a service with a subject/observable in order to share data :

1. Initializing an observable of the subject and returning it (ONE observable of the subject)

```
export class TodoService {

    private _todo = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
    readonly todos$ = this._todo.asObservable();

    constructor() {}

    getTodos$() {
        return this.todos$;
    }
}
```

2. Creating an observable of the subject each time we want to get the data (MULTIPLE observables of the subject)

```
export class TodoService {

    private _todo = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);

    constructor() {}

    getTodos$() {
        return this._todo.asObservable();
    }
}
```

Which of those two approaches should be adopted ? What is the difference between them ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The only difference between the two is the first will only have one instance of an observable linked to the subject, whereas the second will create a new observable each time.  There shouldn't be any practical differences.

I would use one of two alternative approaches depending on if it's actually important to hide the subject.

**Subject Only**

What are you accomplishing by hiding the subject?  Does it really hurt anything if `.next()` is called externally?  Unless there really is a good reason to hide it, I would make the subject read only and let consumers subscribe directly.  I am biased towards this for any services I create that are exclusively used internally.

```
readonly todoSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
```

**Observable Field**

If the subject must be hidden, then just use a read only field for the observable.  Why do the todos$ have to be retrieved from a method?  Unless there's some setup involved in there method, there is none.  This is basically the same as your first example without the method.

```
private _todo = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
readonly todos$ = this._todo.asObservable();
```

Comment: I've definitely run into situations where there are practical differences and have found the most predictable approach is the OP's first one, where the same observable reference is returned.

Comment: @snort Can you elaborate a little bit on the "practical differences"?